# What are the current lossless audio containers and codecs for browser based audio recording in 2022?

Tags: javascript, audio, mediarecorder-api

Audio recording is not my thing but I am on a project that needs to record audio from a web based app.  I am using the `MediaRecorder` API and some of the most recent information I see on containers and codecs is from 2018 on this web site: https://blog.addpipe.com/recording-audio-in-the-browser-using-pure-html5-and-minimal-javascript/

It lists:

- Firefox -- "audio/ogg; codecs=opus"
- Chrome -- "audio/webm; codecs=opus", "audio/webm; codecs=pcm"
- Opera -- "audio/webm; codecs=opus", "audio/webm; codecs=pcm"

It suggests a MediaRecorder replacement called "PolyFill" for Safari and Edge.

I have not tried PolyFill yet but I have tried the other mime type and codec strings above and they all seem to work.  Is this what is current in 2022?

Is there a canonical source for this info?